# Retrieving object model is blank?

Tags: asp.net, object, razor, webmatrix, cloudinary

I have a foreach loop which cycles through a bunch of images, and uploads them using this code:

```
    foreach(var image in fetchimages) {

    string fileName = "https://www.mywebsite.co.uk" + image.ImageOriginalURL;
    var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
    {

        File = new FileDescription(fileName)
    };
    var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams); 

    var mytest = new ImageUploadResult();
    myurl = mytest.SecureUri;

    db.Execute("UPDATE Property_Images SET NewURL = @0 WHERE ImageID = 145", myurl);
}
```

However, each time, the `myurl` variable is empty. I'm thinking i possibly have the `ImageUploadResult()` in the wrong place in the foreach loop?

Comment: you can parse json to object var obj = JSON.parse(response);  then use obj.url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an empty upload result and checking the value there. Please try uploadResult.SecureUri
Also, it's best to check uploadResult.Error to see if an error occurred in the upload.

Comment: That's done the trick! Sorry, i'm new to all this, but you've been very helpful. Thanks